# Ajax Load More Code Breaks When Adding Category ID in $args (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I implemented a AJAX Load More Posts code from one of the guides available on Internet. The code suited me and works well in archive.php. But when I try to use the same code in taxonomy-product-cat.php adding
`$cat_id=get_query_var('cat'); 'cat' => $cat_id` in $args
the code breaks and returns blank.

Here is the complete code I have been using. I think the error is triggered by the JS and since I am not familiar with JS, I would want some help to fix it.

My product-taxonomy-cat.php

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '2',
        'paged' => 1,
    );
    $blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
 
    <?php if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="blog-posts">
            <?php while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $blog_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="loadmore">Load More...</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Registering and localizing AJAX script in functions

```
function blog_scripts() {
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
 
    // Localize the script with new data
    $script_data_array = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'load_more_posts' ),
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-script', 'blog', $script_data_array );
 
    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blog_scripts' );
```

My AJAX Js

```
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': blog.security
        };
 
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if($.trim(response) != '') {
                $('.blog-posts').append(response);
                page++;
            } else {
                $('.loadmore').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

AJAX callback function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
```

Load More Posts Loop in Functions

```
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '2',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
 
    <?php if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $blog_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php
    endif;
 
    wp_die();
}
```

Please help me load more posts with this AJAX when in category as well.

Comment: Product Category doesn't use that query_var. It's taxonomy name is `product_cat` and post type `product`

Comment: I know and use `product` in `post_type` $argument. But didn't understand your point about `product_cat`. Will I be able to get posts from specific category I am in, by adding `tax_query` in $args? But how, could you please elaborate in answer? @HowardE

Comment: Got it fixed buddy! Thanks! `<?php $cat=get_query_var('product_cat'); $args=array( 'post_type'=>'product', 'product_cat'=>$cat, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>'2', 'paged'=>'1' ); $products=new WP_Query($args); ?>`